# SQL Query - to check total amount of each employee and display those employee with amount less than 5000

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, rdbms

I am currently doing a task where i need to calculate the sum of total amount of product each employee has. Then, I need to set a fix amount(5000) and display those employees who have total amount less than the fix amount(5000). Can anyone provide examples of queries for this particular problem?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table T2 will return list of employees less than 5000,then join it with your employee master table T2. Change the table names as needed.

```
 SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE T1 JOIN
 (SELECT EmployeeID,SUM(AMOUNT) AMOUNT FROM PRODUCT
 GROUP BY EmployeeID
 HAVING SUM(AMOUNT)<5000) T2 ON T1.EmployeeID=T2.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: sample data]

Taking the above image as dummy table, you can use this query for getting your appropriate result

```
SELECT productid, price + productid as Amount
FROM Products
where Amount < 15
order by productid
```

Execution of this query will give the result as shown in below image:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 above:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (   SELECT * ,
                  SUM(AMOUNT) OVER ( PARTITION BY EmployeeID ) AS EmpTotal
           FROM   PRODUCT
       ) t
WHERE  t.EmpTotal > 5000;
```